# Parsing Boolean from a json and assigning to a variable does not work when the value is False

Tags: python

Using Python, I've got a function retrieving a list of operations from an API endpoint.
The functino takes a filter argument as a variable in order to filter the results on a given predicate.

Function looks like this:

```
def list_operations(filter=None):
    # make a curl call to the product recognizer
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer  {}'.format(creds.token),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }


    response = requests.get(
        'https://{}/v1alpha1/projects/{}/locations/us-central1/operations'.format(API_ENDPOINT, project),
        headers=headers
    )

    # dump the json response and display their names
    data = json.loads(response.text)

    #add a Metadata element to the operations if it does not exist
    for item in data['operations']:
        if not item.get('metadata'):
            item['metadata'] = {}
            item['metadata']['createTime'] = ''
        else:
            if not item['metadata'].get('createTime'):
                item['metadata']['createTime'] = ''        

    # Order operations by create time if the metadata exists and the createTime exists
    data['operations'] = sorted(data['operations'], key=lambda k: k['done'], reverse=True)

    if filter:
        # filter the operations by the filter value
        # Parse the filter value to get the operation name
        filter_path = filter.split('=')[0].split('.')
        filter_value = filter.split('=')[1]

        #check if the filter_value could be a Boolean
        if filter_value == 'True':
            filter_value = True 
        elif filter_value == 'False':
            filter_value = False

        # iterate backwards to avoid index out of range error using reversed
        for item in reversed(data['operations']):
            # for every element in filter_path, check if it exists
            item_value = item
            for filter_el in filter_path:
                if item_value.get(filter_el):
                    item_value = item_value.get(filter_el)

            
            # if the item value is not equal to the filter value, remove it from the list
            if item_value != filter_value:
                data['operations'].remove(item)
```

My problem is when I'm calling the function with/

```
list_operations(filter='done=False')
```

even when the done key from the response message is False, the assignment of the value to item_value does not work:

```
item_value = item_value.get(filter_el)
```

Using the debugger, item_value is {'name': 'api_path/operation-1676883175156-5f51dc9fc2ad1-b4c56f97-edd1e5be', 'done': False, 'metadata': {'createTime': ''}} instead of False

It works fine when calling

```
list_operations(filter='done=True')
```

I can't see what's missing here ...

[EDIT]
Problem was it the

```
if item_value.get(filter_el):
```

To test existence of the key, should have done:

```
if filter_el in item_value:
```

stupid mistake ...

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads()` loads a JSON to a Python dictionary, so `"done": false` is already converted to `{"done": False}` in Python:

```
import json

d = json.loads("""{"name": "api_path/operation-1676883175156-5f51dc9fc2ad1-b4c56f97-edd1e5be", 
"done": false, 
"metadata": {"createTime": ""}}""")
print(type(d['done']))
>>> <class 'bool'>
```

I don't have your full response so I cannot help beyond this point.

Comment: thanks @Minh-Long, I found the problem with your pointer: my if statement was to check the existence of the key in the dic, but instead I checked the value, in that case it returned false, so never entered the assignment part :
should have done  if filter_el in item_value: instead of if item_value.get(filter_el)